# groovy web services

Tags: web-services, grails, groovy

I have tried to use http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS

In my BuildConfig.groovy I have added: compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules:groovyws:0.5.2'

I then go to Refresh Dependencies and after downloading bunch of stuff, I end up with:

```
Error executing script Compile: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl.getChildNodes()Lorg/w3c/dom/NodeList;" the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/groovy/grails/cli/support/GrailsRootLoader) of the current class, org/apache/xerces/dom/NodeImpl, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for interface org/w3c/dom/Node have different Class objects for the type org/w3c/dom/NodeList used in the signature
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl.getChildNodes()Lorg/w3c/dom/NodeList;" the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/groovy/grails/cli/support/GrailsRootLoader) of the current class, org/apache/xerces/dom/NodeImpl, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for interface org/w3c/dom/Node have different Class objects for the type org/w3c/dom/NodeList used in the signature
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ivy.util.XMLHelper.parseToDom(XMLHelper.java:196)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.m2.PomReader.<init>(PomReader.java:95)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.m2.PomModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(PomModuleDescriptorParser.java:118)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.parser.m2.PomModuleDescriptorParser.parseDescriptor(PomModuleDescriptorParser.java:108)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.DefaultRepositoryCacheManager$MyModuleDescriptorProvider.provideModule(DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.java:659)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.ModuleDescriptorMemoryCache.getStale(ModuleDescriptorMemoryCache.java:68)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.getStaledMd(DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.java:676)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.cache.DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.cacheModuleDescriptor(DefaultRepositoryCacheManager.java:993)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver.parse(BasicResolver.java:546)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.BasicResolver.getDependency(BasicResolver.java:266)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.IBiblioResolver.getDependency(IBiblioResolver.java:503)
    at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.ChainResolver.getDependency(ChainResolver.java:104)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.IvyNode.loadData(IvyNode.java:169)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.VisitNode.loadData(VisitNode.java:287)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:696)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:781)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:704)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:781)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:704)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:769)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:704)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:769)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:704)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.doFetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:781)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.fetchDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:704)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.getDependencies(ResolveEngine.java:576)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine.resolve(ResolveEngine.java:237)
    at org.apache.ivy.core.resolve.ResolveEngine$resolve.call(Unknown Source)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultCompileDependencies_closure9.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy:293)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$_getDefaultCompileDependencies_closure9.doCall(BuildSettings.groovy)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getDefaultCompileDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:293)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.getCompileDependencies(BuildSettings.groovy:278)
    at _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure8.doCall(_GrailsClasspath_groovy:130)
    at _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure8.doCall(_GrailsClasspath_groovy)
    at _GrailsClasspath_groovy.setClasspath(_GrailsClasspath_groovy:190)
    at _GrailsClasspath_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsClasspath_groovy:39)
    at _GrailsEvents_groovy.run(_GrailsEvents_groovy:50)
    at _GrailsEvents_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at _GrailsArgParsing_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at _GrailsArgParsing_groovy.run(_GrailsArgParsing_groovy:29)
    at _GrailsArgParsing_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at _GrailsInit_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at _GrailsInit_groovy.run(_GrailsInit_groovy:37)
    at _GrailsInit_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy.run(_GrailsCompile_groovy:28)
    at _GrailsCompile_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at Compile.run(Compile.groovy:25)
    at Compile$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.prepareTargets(Gant.groovy:606)
Error executing script Compile: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl.getChildNodes()Lorg/w3c/dom/NodeList;" the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/groovy/grails/cli/support/GrailsRootLoader) of the current class, org/apache/xerces/dom/NodeImpl, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for interface org/w3c/dom/Node have different Class objects for the type org/w3c/dom/NodeList used in the signature
```

Anyone can help me with what's gonig on? Why do I get this exception and how to fix it?

Thanks

--MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're entering a dependency madness. Look at your error message for this [`LinkageError`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/LinkageError.html) (I've added some emphasis):

> Error executing script Compile: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "`org.apache.xerces.dom.NodeImpl.getChildNodes()Lorg/w3c/dom/NodeList;`" the class loader (instance of `org/codehaus/groovy/grails/cli/support/GrailsRootLoader`) of the current class, `org/apache/xerces/dom/NodeImpl`, and the class loader (instance of ) for interface `org/w3c/dom/Node` have different Class objects for the type `org/w3c/dom/NodeList` used in the signature

To make things a little more clear (if that's not already the case), there is a conflict between two of your dependencies. As you appear to use Grails, I would tend to say to you that the version of GroovyWS you use is not compatible with your current installation of Grails. Have you tried to install groovyWS using Grails command-line ? I mean, calling [`install-dependency`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-dependency.html) ? If not, I would suggest you replace your dependecy with a call to

```
install-dependency org.codehaus.groovy.modules:groovyws
```

This way, Grails would use its own compatibility mechanism.

If that's not enough, try to see in [that guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#3.7.1%20Configurations%20and%20Dependencies) how to exclude offending dependencies.

**EDIT** You could also follow some advices from [this blog entry](http://little418.com/2009/05/grails-throws-javalanglinkageerror-on-startup.html).